# IRS publication 936 weirdness. Deductible home mortgage interest limits and zero-pay or cash-out refinance

Tags: united-states, taxes, mortgage, tax-deduction, refinance

There is a 750,000 home acquisition loan limit for deducting mortgage interest. This limit only applies to "home acquisition debt" (excludes the cash-out part). However this is used to adjust the whole mortgage interest (which include interest on the cash-out part).

This looks like a weird bug.

Imagine a hypothetical situation:

You have a mortgage balance of $750,000. At the beginning of the year (for simplicity, Jan 1 or during the previous year  even), you refinance the mortgage with cash-out, bringing your loan to $2,000,000. You pay interest for this $2,000,000 loan which gets reported on Form 1098. The average home acquisition loan balance is $750,000 for the year. So the interest deduction limitation coefficient is 1.0 and you can essentially deduct 100% of the Form 1089 interest.

Am I understanding the instructions correctly? Or am I expected to split the interest somehow? The publication says nothing about splitting. It just asks to input the "Total amount of interest that you paid."

P.S. Publication 936 has more weird math. For example, the way it sums the average loan balances and divides them by the sum of all interest paid does not look like something mathematically correct. If the loans are non-overlapping (refinance), it would be more correct to calculate the deductible portion of the interest separately for each loan and then sum those. They also propose to find the loan balance average by averaging the year start and end balances which is not correct for a non-linear loan balance function like a mortgage.

[Publication 936](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/p936--2021.pdf)

**Refinanced home acquisition debt**

> Any secured debt you use to refinance home acquisition debt is treated as home acquisition debt.
> However, the new debt will qualify as home acquisition debt only up to the amount of the balance of the old mortgage principal just before
> the refinancing. Any additional debt not used to
> buy, build, or substantially improve a qualified
> home isn't home acquisition debt.

**Mixed-use mortgages**

> A mixed-use mortgage is a loan that consists of more than one of
> the three categories of debt (grandfathered
> debt, home acquisition debt, and home equity
> debt). For example, a mortgage you took out
> during the year is a mixed-use mortgage if you
> used its proceeds partly to refinance a mortgage that you took out in an earlier year to buy your home (home acquisition debt) and partly to
> buy a car (home equity debt).
> Complete lines 1, 2, and 7 of Table 1 by including the separate average balances of any
> grandfathered debt and home acquisition debt
> (determined by the date the debt was acquired)
> in your mixed-use mortgage. Don’t use the
> methods described earlier in this section to figure the average balance of either category. Instead, for each category, use the following
> method.
>
> 1. Figure the balance of that category of debt
>    for each month. This is the amount of the
>    loan proceeds allocated to that category,
>    reduced by your principal payments on the
>    mortgage previously applied to that category. Principal payments on a mixed-use
>    mortgage are applied in full to each category of debt, until its balance is zero, in the
>    following order.
>
> a. First, any home equity debt not used
> to buy, build, or substantially improve
> the home.
>
> b. Next, any grandfathered debt.
>
> c. Finally, any home acquisition debt.
>
> 2. Add together the monthly balances figured
>    for b and c in (1).
>    Complete line 12 of Table 1 using the figure
>    from line (2) above.

**Line 12: Average home acquisition debt balance**

> Figure the average balance for the current year
> of each outstanding home mortgage. Add the
> average balances together and enter the total
> on line 12. See Average Mortgage Balance,
> earlier.
> Note. If the average balance consists of
> more than one category of debt (grandfathered
> debt, home acquisition debt, and home equity
> debt), see Mixed-use mortgages, earlier, to figure the average mortgage balance.

**Line 13: Total amount of interest that you paid.**

> If you make payments to a financial institution,
> or to a person whose business is making loans,
> you should get Form 1098 or a similar statement from the lender. This form will show the
> amount of interest to enter on line 13. Also, include on this line any other interest payments
> made on debts secured by a qualified home for
> which you didn't receive a Form 1098. Don't include points or mortgage insurance premiums
> on this line.

Line 15: Deductible home mortgage interest

```
Deductible_interest = Total_interest * (750,000 / Average_home_acquidition_debt)
```

Comment: This is complicated enough to the average taxpayer as it is, I don't think optimizing for mathematical correctness will provide significant benefits to either the government or the taxpayer.

Comment: So, do you think that I'm correct and I do not need to do any splitting of the mortgage interest?

Comment: I'd say that the correct variant (separate calculations for the loan before and after refinance) seems easier. How am I expected to calculate the average balance when the loan amount raises in the middle of the year? treating this as two separate loans going down is much easier. The publication has examples for a really convoluted cases like refinancing grandfathered debts with balloon payments and mixed-use mortgages.  But it does not help for the most common case: refinance a normal post-2017 mortgage and cash-out or zero-pay refinance.

Comment: If you're just refinancing a normal post 2017 mortgage, without cash-out, then you just have one mortgage at any given time and you do the simple averaging and that's it. Once you add cash-out part (unless it's deductible, for renovations and such) then you'll have a much more complex situation. In any case, you can do whatever math you want, but if you do something other than what the IRS expects, even if it is mathematically correct and precise, expect to be required to prove it at audit.

Comment: I just don't fully understand what IRS wants in case of zero-cost/cash-out refinance. Do they want me to average the the balance that goes down then jumps and goes down again? Or do they want me to average the balance that goes down then stays the same (the home acquisition debt part)? What do they want me to do with interest? Just sum it up from both Form 1098? It's weird to do proportionality in one place (loan) but not the other (interest). And this makes me get a slightly bigger return, which might concern IRS.

Comment: I didn't have that much money to pay for all the refinance closing costs and points. I practically had to use zero-closing-costs option. Which is essentially a small cash-out (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: It depends. If your new balance is higher than the old balance then yes, you essentially cashed out your closing costs, but that's not what is called "no-cost". True no-cost refinances you roll over the same balance with no additional costs (the new bank is interested in the interest you'll pay). I've had that a couple of times, usually small local banks/CUs do that.